# Отменить вывод определенной категории из the_terms

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress. Как отменить вывод определенных категорий в данной `php` функции? Мне нужно убрать три категории, можно подцепиться за `id` или `slag`.

```
<?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'category', '', '' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используя `the_terms` вы не можете исключить категории, вместо этой функции вы можете использовать `get_terms` у которой есть больше настроек. пример вывода ссылок на категории поста с возможностью исключить некоторые по id

```
    $post_terms = get_terms( [
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'object_ids' => get_the_ID(),
        // 'exclude' => []  в этом параметре вы можете задать id категорий которые нужно исключить
    ] );

    foreach ( $post_terms as $term ) {
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
        <?php
    }
```